# This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: tar

**`[root@c0002242 lfeng]# tar -zxvf /opt/test/ALLscripts.tar.gz -C /opt/test1`**

tar: This does not look like a tar archive

tar: Skipping to next header

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Could you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 7):

Run the command

```
$ file ALLscripts.tar.gz
```

Compare the output, if it's gzip (as shown below) then use `unzip` tool to extract it

```
$ ALLscripts.tar.gz: gzip compressed data,from Unix
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error because my file was not downloaded yet and I was trying to extract it :).